# How to rotate a really fancy imshow on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, imshow

I have been representing an array of arrays of data with imshow. It has a colourbar to change the scale:

```
dataset: array([[4.08468330e-10, 2.36415270e-11, 6.58846951e-12, ...,
        2.27156279e-12, 4.23543198e-12, 4.40911000e-12],
       [4.07275560e-10, 2.46574163e-11, 4.82123872e-12, ...,
        2.39588823e-12, 2.42245604e-12, 3.58778000e-12],
       [4.06226210e-10, 2.44212517e-11, 5.70813892e-12, ...,
        2.79494406e-12, 2.90031792e-12, 4.51387000e-12],
       ...,
       [2.98255320e-10, 9.82796704e-12, 3.75858712e-11, ...,
        9.35899785e-12, 6.98967777e-12, 5.09198000e-12],
       [3.00062620e-10, 9.76252520e-12, 3.67877560e-11, ...,
        8.82046279e-12, 8.25714835e-12, 5.48396000e-12],
       [3.05101120e-10, 1.00383871e-11, 3.81238519e-11, ...,
        8.50893319e-12, 7.30771687e-12, 6.40150000e-12]])
```

[The fancy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPVsC.png)

Beautiful, isn't it?
 I represent it like

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
img = ax.imshow(Array,extent=[linescan[0]*1e3,linescan[-1]*1e3, 0,linescan.length], aspect = 'auto', interpolation='quadric')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.9)
cb = plt.colorbar(img)
axcolor = escala


axFFT_cmin = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axFFT_cmax  = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])


sFFT_cmin = Slider(axFFT_cmin, 'min', minFFT, maxFFT, valinit=FFT_min)
sFFT_cmax = Slider(axFFT_cmax, 'max', minFFT, maxFFT, valinit=FFT_max)

def updateFFT(val, s=None):
    _cmin = sFFT_cmin.val
    _cmax = sFFT_cmax.val
    img.set_clim([_cmin, _cmax])
    plt.draw()

sFFT_cmin.on_changed(updateFFT)
sFFT_cmax.on_changed(updateFFT)
#show everything
plt.show()
```

However, to represent it, the most beautiful way is to do it twisted 90 degrees clockwise. I have tried by setting the axis limits as it is explained here:
https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html

but I am too new with python (4 months) to be able to implement it.
Matplotlib normaly represents arrays of arrays departing from top, left; and you can easily change that to bottom, left; but not to bottom, right.
 If anybody has some advice/example/help, it would be really appreciated. Thank you.

PD: I know i can edit the data to do it easily, but i want to do many interactive features to the graph, some already done. Maybe I am being too fussy, but the most efficient way to do it is not to transpose an array of 1.000.000 ints, but represent them in a different way.

Comment: You need to change the *data*, not the the matplotlib representation of it. So you either need [`numpy.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) or [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) depending on what you mean by "twisted 90 degrees clockwise".

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose your input array. Checkout the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)